# Data sources for dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

The documentation for the `join` functions in the `dplyr` R package discusses what happens if "x and y are not from the same data source", but does not explain what that means. What is a "data source" in the context of `dplyr`, and what does it mean for x to be "from" a data source? If I do

```
x <- read.csv('xfile.csv')
y <- read.csv('yfile.csv')
```

are `x` and `y` from different data sources?

What does the documentation mean when it says "`y` will be copied into the same src as `x`" if they are from different data sources?

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. I suspect this will be on topic on [SO], so we can try to migrate it there.

Comment: Primarily impacts when one dplyr source is in one _external_ database table and the other is in a different table. In-session, in-memory `tbl_df`s don't have this issue.

Comment: Since `dplyr` is also an interface for database, i think in case of `csv` file, `x` and `y` are their respective source however it will be different when using database connections. In the later case, you can have multiple tables from the same connection where you might want to join or do other operations.